# UICollectionview with sections side by side in vertical layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout

After several days of searching, I give up the search and turn to you. I would like a layout like the one shown in the picture. I don't know what the right way should look like, should I use the flow layout or the compositional layout. This question has also been asked in the developer forum.
[Apple Deverloper Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125702)

There it says at the end: "To achieve what you're asking in the question, you'd need to use a single section that contains nested NSCollectionLayoutGroups. A horizontal group with vertical sub-groups should get you close to the desired layout."

*But, I want to have more than one section!?*

**Vertical scroll direction**

[image]

Comment: Have you find an answer for this? I am also wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, didn´t find any solution.

Comment: @GibsonNeunundsiebzig Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, i did not.